# Why does my Python code needs so much memory?

Tags: python

Can you please explain me why my code below needs so much memory

```
    def new_form(teleport):
        d=dict()
        for i in teleport.split(','):
            h1,h2=i[0],i[1]
            d.setdefault(h1,[]).append(h2)
            d.setdefault(h2,[]).append(h1)
        return d

    def telepor(teleports_string):
        d=new_form(teleports_string)
        queue=[('1','1')]
        while queue:
            current,path=queue.pop(0)
            if len(set(path))==8 and path[-1]=="1":
                return path
            for each in d[current]:
                if (current+each) in path:
                    continue
                queue.append((each,path+each))
```

Inputs are string type like ("13,14,23,25,34,35,47,56,58,76,68") and I must find a way throw this graph

Comment: What does "throw this graph" mean?

Comment: How much memory is it using?